# Critical error detected c0000374 while freeing the loaded dll by FreeLibrary

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll

I have met a memory error when I try to free an user-defined DLL. If you do not want to know the background of this problem, I recommend you to read my problem from the beginning of the section 2. **user-defined DLL**.

## Background

In my program, I need to use a third-party library. **In the following part I call it `LIB-A` / `DLL-A`**. The abstract process of this library could be descripted by using 4 functions:

```
initResources(): initialze the configuration.
callAPI_to_saveAsFile(...): main process.
freeMem(...): free memory of returned data.
destroyResources(): free memory of the configuration.
```

The used `LIB-A` has referred `ice34d.dll`, and `iceutil34d.dll`. By adding the lib and included files in my project **(I call this program `exe-A`)**, I have found these functions could work well.

But now I have to use **another method** to refer the `DLL-A`. In other words, I have to use `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` and `FreeLibrary` to complete this task. Since I have found that the `DLL-A` does not provide any avaliable interface of the above functions, I try to remove `DLL-A` from the folder containing `exe-A`. The result shows that **`DLL-A` is not a valid file**, `exe-A` could work well without it.

## User-defined DLL

Because the `DLL-A` is invalid, I have to write a user-defined DLL to wrap the above 4 functions, **I call this program `DLL-B`**. `DLL-B` has be linked with such libs:

```
iced.lib
iceutild.lib
LIB-A
```

Although `DLL-A` is invalid, `LIB-A` is necessary, because I infer that the above 4 founctions are not only declared but also defined in `LIB-A`, and `DLL-A` is actually empty. After setting the libs and included files, I write 4 wrapping functions. Here are the main part of .h file and .cpp file.

.h file: (some parameters are omitted)

```
#include "LIBA.h"
#ifdef MYLIBDLL
    #define CM_EXTERN extern "C" _declspec(dllimport)
#else
    #define CM_EXTERN extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)
#endif

CM_EXTERN int w_initResources();
CM_EXTERN int w_callAPI_to_saveAsFile(...);
CM_EXTERN int w_destroyResources();
CM_EXTERN int w_freeMem(...);
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "../music-lib/release_dll/iced.lib") 
#pragma comment (lib, "../music-lib/release_dll/iceutild.lib") 
#pragma comment (lib, "../music-lib/release_dll/DLLA.lib") 

int w_initResources(){
    return initResources();
}

int w_destroyResources(){
    return destroyResources();
}

int w_freeMem(...){
    return freeMem(...);
}

int w_callAPI_to_saveAsFile(...){
    return callAPI_to_saveAsFile(...);
}

char* w_callAPI_to_downFileByte(char* fileURL,char *ret_bytes){
    return callAPI_to_downFileByte(fileURL, ret_bytes);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

## Problem

After all, I begin to write a test program **(I call it `exe-B`)**. In this program, I use such codes to load `DLL-B`:

.h file:

```
typedef int (*callAPI_to_saveAsFile_ptr)(...);
typedef int (*initResources_ptr)();
typedef int (*destroyResources_ptr)();
typedef int (*freeMem_ptr)(...);
```

.cpp file:

```
callAPI_to_saveAsFile_ptr Proc_API = NULL;
initResources_ptr init_API = NULL;
destroyResources_ptr destru_API = NULL;
freeMem_ptr free_API = NULL;

HINSTANCE h = LoadLibraryA("DLLB.dll");
cout << "ERROR:" << GetLastError() << endl;
if (h){
    Proc_API = (callAPI_to_saveAsFile_ptr)GetProcAddress(h, "w_callAPI_to_saveAsFile");
    init_API = (initResources_ptr)GetProcAddress(h, "w_initResources");
    destru_API = (destroyResources_ptr)GetProcAddress(h, "w_destroyResources");
    free_API = (freeMem_ptr)GetProcAddress(h, "w_freeMem");
    cout << "Have loaded: " << "DLLB.dll" << " successfully!" << endl;
}
else{
    cout << "Do not find this DLL:" << "DLLB.dll" << endl;
    FreeLibrary(h);
    return 0x100;
}
int errorflag=0;
if (Proc_API==NULL){
    cout << "Function not loaded: callAPI_to_saveAsFile" << endl;
    errorflag = errorflag | 0x001;
}
if (init_API==NULL){
    cout << "Function not loaded: initResources" << endl;
    errorflag = errorflag | 0x002;
}
if (destru_API==NULL){
    cout << "Function not loaded: destroyResources" << endl;
    errorflag = errorflag | 0x004;
}
if (CMISS_free_API==NULL){
    cout << "Function not loaded: freeMem" << endl;
    errorflag = errorflag | 0x008;
}
if (errorflag!=0){
    FreeLibrary(h);
    return 0x100 | errorflag;
}
cout << "Function loaded successfully!" << endl;
...Perform above functions...
if(h)
    FreeLibrary(h);
    return 0;
```

It is confusing that even the program could be compiled well, GetLastError() returns 0, and all of the 4 founctions are performed well. However, once I let the program free the DLL instance, I would receive such an error:

```
Critical error detected c0000374
exeB.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

If I do not free the library, there will be no error in this program.

To prove my guess, I have done another 2 experiments:

#### Exp1

I write a DLL(`DLL-C`) to wrap another library (`LIB-D`) designed by myself. And I load `DLL-C` by similiar method in the section. Problem. The result shows that `DLL-C` could be freed without error. The only difference between DLL-C and DLL-B is that DLL-B load the third-party libs(`ice`, `LIB-A`), and DLL-C load a simple library (`LIB-D`) designed by myself. It seems that this error is triggered by the third-party libs. Unfortunately, I could not see the detail of these external libs.

#### Exp2

I change the .cpp file as follow:

```
HINSTANCE h = LoadLibraryA("DLLB.dll");
cout << "ERROR:" << GetLastError() << endl;
if (h){
    cout << "H_Valid!" << endl;
    FreeLibrary(h);
    cout << "Have loaded: " << "DLLB.dll" << " successfully and free it!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else{
    cout << "Do not find this DLL:" << "DLLB.dll" << endl;
    FreeLibrary(h);
    return 0x100;
}
```

It is appalling that although I do nothing with the loaded `DLL-B`, once I load it, I could not free it safely. The error is the same as above error in section. Problem.

```
Critical error detected c0000374
exeB.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

How could I solve this problem? Whether does it mean that I could not free the library but use it normally?

Comment: I suggest you first do it in C, not C++. I see no reason yet for C++. This can eliminate problems of the more complex C++ compiler/linker/loader.

Comment: Oh, in fact, I have used C++ and this problem exists. To eliminate other influences from C++ libraries, I use a more simple form to test this problem.

Comment: Just because a program crashes at a particular point -- such as unloading a shared library -- doesn't mean that's where the bug is. The bug can be anywhere in your code, that executed at some previous point and ended up corrupting the internal memory heap, but did not crash and execution continued until this point, when a rather disruptive operation (unloading a shared library) encountered the corrupted memory and crashed. Your bug can be anywhere in your code. Welcome to C++.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level.

Comment: after this line: `HINSTANCE h = LoadLibraryA("DLLB.dll");`, the posted code calls `cout << "ERROR:" << GetLastError() << endl;` without first testing to see if there was an error event.  then the code has `if( h ) ... else ... FreeLibrary(h);`  However, the library failed to load, so calling `FreeLibrary()` is an error.

Comment: what are you expecting these kinds of lines `typedef int (*initResources_ptr)();` to accomplish?   What they are doing is giving an `int` new names.   If your trying to create prototypes for the functions, use: ` int (*initResources_ptr)();`  and even that is just declaring a function pointer that takes no parameters and returns `int`.  BTW: when writing prototypes for functions that take no parameters, place `void` between the parens.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks! Your answer could help me understand my problem!

Comment: @user3629249 Now I have known the problem! It is of nonsense. The problem exists in the extern `LIB-A` (it is from others). This lib has 2 versions, one is used for debugging, the other is used for releasing. I have test the debug version and confirm that it is valid. But I have not expected that the release version has errors. I build another c-project and refer `LIB-A` implicitly. And... Ooops! I have gotten critical error detected c0000374! In fact, the process I have shown in this question is correct technically.

Comment: @user3629249 `typedef int (*initResources_ptr)();` is necessary in this example. Because in the following part, I call `GetProcAddress` and let it return a function to a variable pointer. If I do not use `typedef`, I could not use the declaration to create such an pointer.